# Are there any artifactory repository naming/configuration conventions?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I am recently working on setting up Artifactory on my virtual server. Basically everything works fine but I did not find any conventions how to setup the repositories used by my projects.

Is there any recommendation/guide to either create an own repository for each (multi module) project (e.g. myProject-release-local) or alternatively to put them all to the same repository (e.g. libs-release-local)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much isolation you need/want. If you want to tightly control the dependencies of each build, separate repositories might work better. In any case, each build should only have to list a single repository in its build script. This can be achieved by aggregating physical repositories into virtual repositories.

Comment: Thx for your quick response! Assuming I have a project called movieDB with 3 submodules (extApis, core, web), would it be okay to use one repo, let's say artifactory/movieDB for my init.gradle, one artifactory/distributions for my gradlew, and one artifactory/movieDB-snapshot-local for publishing or do you think this is a bad approach?

Comment: I'd put the Gradle distribution into the same place as any other third-party dependency. You could be even stricter and distinguish between (say) tools, test dependencies, and production dependencies, but this might be overkill and I wouldn't start out like that. You do want a separate repository for publishing your own artifacts. I don't know what the purpose of a repository for `init.gradle` would be. If you are uncertain, why not go with Artifactory's defaults (I assume it still defines some repos by default).

Comment: Thanks Peter, I think I will stick with the defaults and enhance it later on as you suggested

Comment: I recently cloned the Gradle library from github.com and had a look how you solved the Artifactory setup for your projects. As it looks like you basically sticked with the defaults but created a virtual repository 'libs' to resolve all artefacts needed for the build?